# Lookup, with three if results

Tags: excel-formula

Ok, here is my issue... I get a #VALUE! as a result, but I can't figure out why... any help would be appreciated.

The first thing I am doing is referring to a ticket number which is in **A2 on the same page**, once found in the first lookup it then looks in **Ticket_Import!G2** to see if the ticket is **open** or **closed**.  If open then it says "Open" if closed it says "Closed", and if it's neither it is "Waiting". I can't figure why I am getting for all intended purposes a value error.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is the formula I'm using.

```
=LOOKUP($A2,Ticket_Import!$B:$B,IF(Ticket_Import!$G2="closed","Closed",IF(Ticket_Import!G2="open","Open","Waiting")))
```

Comment: usually means can't fund **A2** value in column **B**

Comment: A2's number is 1870.  

B2 is 1870, if it can't find it two rows down, I think there is an issue here... 

the reason I am using B:B is because I have over 10K worth of numbers to go through.

Comment: @BigBen I am using the lookup to look for a specific number in a column. Once found it then looks right and verifies if it's open or closed. If its neither it's waiting.

Comment: I prefer the function Index with Match. What column in the sheet Ticket_Import has the ticket number and what column is the open or close in?

Comment: @Edward B is where the number is, G is where the open, close and technically waiting is.  But I figured if it wasn't open and close, the final "false" would be waiting anyway.

Comment: The way you're using `LOOKUP` doesn't make sense here... the third argument should be a *result_vector*, namely a *range*. See the [docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Index/Match vs Lookup

```
=if(index(Ticket_Import!$B:$G,Match($A2,Ticket_Import!$B:$B,0),6)="Open","Open",if(index(Ticket_Import!$B:$G,Match($A2,Ticket_Import!$B:$B,0),6)="Closed","Closed","Waiting"))
```

Comment: index takes the array first, then (exact match from the 0) matches row by the lookup value within the entire column, the last number "6" pulls the column G from the array

Comment: @MattRidge - the key part is that the `IF` logic is *outside* the `INDEX/MATCH`. Your `LOOKUP` formula doesn't make sense because you've included it *inside* the function. To be honest, I'm guessing all you need is a simple `VLOOKUP` but I'd need a screenshot of your data to confirm.

Comment: @Edward, sorry I was AFK (spending time with my son I was late getting home)

In any case, here is a file to go through... I used your code, but it really isn't making sense on why it's working... can you walk me through it a bit if possible, it be greatly appreciated. 

http://mpridge.com/files/

Comment: @MattRidge first `if` then does the first index which has an array and matches your cell to the first column in the array for the first row that matches exactly then pulls the 6th column of the array which is column G and checks if equals "Open" and sets if true; if false does a second check same way on if it equals "Closed".